# Carregar um conteúdo da página apenas ao clicar

Tags: php, javascript, html

Como faço para que um conteúdo seja exibido dentro de uma página, e que tanto a exibição quanto o carregamento desse conteúdo ocorra apenas ao clicar em um link (sem o carregamento da página inteira, apenas do elemento que desejo).

O objetivo é exibir vídeos de outros sites com o código de incorporação desses, porém apenas ao clicar, evitando a exibição de vários vídeos na mesma página sem a solicitação do usuário, deixando o carregamento da página mais leve.

Comment: Sem o carregamento, teria que ser via JAVASCRIPT + AJAX. Porém, para ajudar de uma forma objetiva, preciso que detalhe melhor o seu contexto.

Comment: Eu possuo diversos Códigos de incorporação (Embeds) e Títulos para esses vídeos em uma base de dados, e gostaria de criar um link (usando esses  títulos), e ao clicar nesse link, iria ser carregado (abaixo desse link) o embed referente. Já sei como fazer a manipulação dos dados, o problema é que não sei como fazer esse carregamento apenas ao clicar no link